# Executing a C++ program from a python program

Tags: python, c++, ipc

Here's the scenario, I have to run clustering algorithm over 10000 data points. I have precomputed the distances between the data points and stored them in a file. Since Python is slow in I/O intensive tasks, I am writing this clustering algorithm in C++. The main issue is that the clustering algorithm will run several times and I have to switch between the python code and C++ code. Something like this

```
Read Distances from text_file (C++)
Run Clustering Algorithm (C++)

Use the result of this algorithm in main python code

Run clustering algorithm again (C++)
```

Now I don't want to read the distance file again and again, as it already takes around 17 seconds and the file has over 500 million entries. Something like pausing the execution of C++ code and running the code again when needed. So, how could this be achieved??

Comment: boost::python, cython, or simply wrapping your code in C and calling with ctypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just an idea:

Can you maybe run the c++ part your program within your main python program. You can do that by looking at the answers in this [[Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python]). You can use Adapter design pattern to pre-process the output in your c++ program so it becomes compatible with the data structures used in your main python program and vice-versa.